# Minutes between two times in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I got a string "14:05"

How could I compare it with current time and get time difference in minutes?

Difference may be both negative and positive(current time is before string or after)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateParse = ""

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
let dateNSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date) //date = "14:05"
let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
let timeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(dateNSDate!)
```

timeInterval is in seconds.

If you want to convert seconds to days, hours, minutes ans seconds :

```
print(String((seconds / 86400)) + " days")
print(String((seconds % 86400) / 3600) + " hours")
print(String((seconds % 3600) / 60) + " minutes")
print(String((seconds % 3600) % 60) + " seconds")
```

So your string is like this :

```
let string = "\((seconds % 86400) / 3600)) : \((seconds % 3600) / 60))
```

Comment: Divide by 60 to get minutes.

Comment: Where did `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` came from? It's `"HH:mm"` in the question.

Comment: To compare, you need a precise date ?

Comment: @MichelRobico no,only time is needed

Comment: @MichelRobico, To answer the question, you need to use data from question, and not assume something.

Comment: @MichelRobico, `currentDate` line is invalid, you can't get `Date` from `Date`.

Comment: @MichelRobico error "cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expeted argument type 'String' "   on pre-last line

Comment: @Alex Sorry I forgot one line

Comment: @MichelRobico hi!
Can you please help with converting this solution to output time in HH:mm format?

Comment: @Alex Can you be more precise ?

Comment: @MichelRobico  i have string "14:00"(start time) and an end time(current time,let's say 18:30)   i want to get diffrence between them in HH:mm (04:30)

Comment: @Alex My solution is above. And you have already validated another answer visibly.

Comment: @MichelRobico i'm using your solution right now,but i tried to convert seconds to HH:mm

Comment: @MichelRobico thank you!
and how to get both hour and minute in one string? like "04:30" (HH:mm)

Comment: @MichelRobico thanks!
any idea how to make values < 10 look like 09:07, not 9:7 ?

Answer (score 25):

`Calendar` has powerful methods to do that.

Any explicit math with `60`, `3600` or even `86400` is not needed at all.

- Convert the time string to `Date`.
- Get the `hour` and `minute` date components from the current and the converted date.
- Calculate the difference with `dateComponents(:from:to:` by specifying only the `minute` component.

---

```
let time = "14:05"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let timeDate = dateFormatter.date(from: time)!
let calendar = Calendar.current
let timeComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeDate)
let nowComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())

let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: timeComponents, to: nowComponents).minute!
```

Comment: this does not take into account the actual date, its literally just comparing the hour and minute numbers.
Date1 could be 5 years ago at 12:00pm and the Date2 could be today at 12:01pm and the result would tell you, incorrectly, the different is 1 minute apart. 
Unless that's what you want, that's incorrect.
I presume you would want the actual, total number of minutes between to dates.

Answer (score 20):

For getting minutes difference between two dates I have done like below.

You can keep this method in common class and call.

```
func getMinutesDifferenceFromTwoDates(start: Date, end: Date) -> Int
   {

       let diff = Int(end.timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970)

       let hours = diff / 3600
       let minutes = (diff - hours * 3600) / 60
       return minutes
   }
```

Comment: This methods givens incorrect difference between two dates. If you send parameters - 3:30 pm and 3:25 pm, it will give you difference as 5, which is correct. But if you send parameters 3:30 pm and 2:25 pm, it still gives the difference as 5, where as it should be 65.

Answer (score 9):

Despite all the answers, I found Narashima's one the most straight forward. However, here there is a more straightforward one.

```
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Date(timeInterval: 86400, since: startDate)

let diffSeconds = Int(endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 - startDate.timeIntervalSince1970)

let minutes = diffSeconds / 60
let hours = diffSeconds / 3600
```

Comment: `let diffSeconds = Int(endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)`

Answer (score 3):

**Objective-C version**

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";

    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"14:15"];

    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

    NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date1];

    NSDateComponents *components2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitYear| NSCalendarUnitDay| NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:date2];

    components1.year = components2.year;
    components1.month = components2.month;
    components1.day = components2.day;

    NSDate *date3 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components1];

    NSInteger timeIntervalInMinutes = [date3 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2]/60;
```

**Swift version**

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "14:05")

    let date2 = NSDate()

    var components1 = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date1!)

    let components2 = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .day, .month, .year], from: date2 as Date)

    components1.year = components2.year;
    components1.month = components2.month;
    components1.day = components2.day;

    let date3 = NSCalendar.current.date(from: components1)

    let timeIntervalInMinutes = date3!.timeIntervalSince(date2 as Date)/60
```

Comment: This answer is correct, notice how the year, month and day components are normalised. If this is omitted, your results would be skewed.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below for a Swift implementation of @Alexey Kudley's answer. Please show him some love for the original solution.

```
let inputString = "07:22"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

guard let inputDate = formatter.date(from: inputString) else { return }
let nowDate = Date()

var inputComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: inputDate)
let nowComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: nowDate)

inputComps.year = nowComps.year
inputComps.month = nowComps.month
inputComps.day = nowComps.day

guard let normalisedInputDate = Calendar.current.date(from: inputComps) else { return }

let intervalInMins = nowDate.timeIntervalSince(normalisedInputDate) / 60
```

Answer (score 1):

`func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents` returns the difference between two dates.

```swift
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: date1, to: date2).minute
```

Comment: Please note that the OP states that one of their two dates is currently in a string format. Your answer should also show how to convert their given string into a date first, then your solution would actually be the better solution of all given answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it like this:

```
let receivedTimeString = "14:05"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

if let date = formatter.date(from: receivedTimeString) {
    // getting the number of minutes in the receivedTimeString:
    let receivedTimeHoursMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) * 60
    let receivedTimeMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)
    let totalreceivedTimeMinutes = receivedTimeHoursMinutes + receivedTimeMinutes

    // getting the number of minutes in today:
    let todayHoursMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) * 60
    let todayMinutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
    let todayTimeMinutes = todayHoursMinutes + todayMinutes

    // difference in minutes (could be negative):
    let difference = totalreceivedTimeMinutes - todayTimeMinutes
    print(difference)
}
```